# Simplifying logic circuit

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, nand

I've been trying to simplify a combinational circuit and wanted to know whether there was any simpler way of solving such questions. Do we have to find all the outputs and such or we can use a simpler method ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please include the image in your question rather than as an external link.

Comment: Here are some search terms which may help you: "de morgan's law" , "truth table", "karnaugh map"

Comment: Why not start by making a table with columns for A to G? Just list out a row for every permutation of A to D, and then by hand work out for F and G. Perhaps you might see some obvious simplifications by just looking over the table. It is a way to start. Also, you could then show that work here. It might encourage others to add some thoughts for you.

Comment: No simpler method.  But there are tricks you pick up with experience.  I'd use deMorgan's symbols for \$T_4\$, \$T_5\$ and \$T_6\$.  But at this point that is meaningless to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using deMorgan's symbols for \$T_4\$, \$T_5\$ & \$T_6\$.  A NAND is a negative OR.

[image: DeMorgan's Circuit]

$$F = \bar A + \overline {\overline {ABC}} + \overline {\overline {BC}}$$

$$F = \bar A + ABC + BC$$

$$F = \bar A + BC$$

$$ G = \overline {(\bar A + BC)(\overline {\overline {ABC}} + \bar B + \overline {\overline {BCD}})(\overline {\overline {BC}} + \overline {\overline {BCD}} + \bar D)} $$
$$ G = \overline {(\bar A + BC)(ABC + \bar B + BCD)(BC + BCD + \bar D)} $$
$$ G = \overline {(\bar A + BC)(ABC + \bar B + BCD)(BC + \bar D)} $$
$$ G = \overline {(\bar A D + BC)(ABC + \bar B + BCD)} $$

G can still be simplified.  Otherwise check the math.

But deMorgan's can simplify the process if applied correctly.